# Getting ujson error while installing Rasa-x on ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, pip, rasa, rasa-x, ujson

I am trying to install Rasa-x using pip. I am getting a weird ujson error.
pip version --> pip 20.1.1
python3 version --> python 3.6
ubuntu 20.04
I am attaching the error below.
`Building wheel for ujson (setup.py) ... error`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please add some commands that you run, and the exact error message you get? It would be essential for finding a solution for your problem. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show the full text of the error.